# HTTP request to external REST resource from inside Singleton EJB in wildfly 27

Tags: json, http, get, ejb, wildfly

I have a Singleton EJB deployed in an EAR on wildfly 27 with a scheduled method to provide data for a WebSocket deployed in the same EAR.
The application is supposed to gather stock and fx quotes from external resources and provide users with this data. Currently the data is being mocked to allow for testing but eventually the bean needs to read the data externally.
I'm aware that opening a URLConnection in an EJB is critical so my question is, how can this be achieved?
I guess I need to implement a resource adapter for that but I lack the knowledge to do so and the docs from wildfly are rather limitted.
Most welcome would be an example or an alternative how this could be achieved.

The Singleton is rather trivial:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class QuotesJob {
     
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(QuotesJob.class);
    
    private static Map<String, QuotesListener> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 
    private static Random random;
    
    private Map<String, Float> quote = new HashMap<>(); 
    {
        quote.put("EURUSD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("USDCAD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("NZDUSD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("AUDUSD", 0.00000f);
        random = new Random();
    }
    
    
    @PostConstruct
    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/6", persistent=false)
    public void perform() {
        logger.info("quotes update...");
        quote.forEach((k, v) -> {
            quote.put(k, random.nextFloat());  // mock data
        });
        notifyListeners();
    }
    
    private void notifyListeners() {
        logger.info("notify listeners: " + quote);
        listeners.forEach((k, v) -> {
            v.consume(quote);
        });
    }

    public void addQuotesListener(String clazz, QuotesListener listener) {
        listeners.put(clazz, listener);
    }
    
    
    @PreDestroy
    public void endJob() {
        listeners.clear();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You just need to make a HTTP request right? I would use the `java.net.http.HttpClient` to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . Yes, simple HTTP-requests to RESTful resources outside wildfly. So you see no issue, even when there are up to 5 requests in each phase. The data needs to be gathered from different sources. Shouldn't I at least implement it asynchronously? Anyway, I will test your suggestion.

Comment: That's fairly easy to do with the `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Works like charm, thanks again. I was obviously thinking too complicated.

This is the code now. I'm using a test API so the responses are useless but proof of concept.
On re-deployment the worker method stops and resumes after deployment. No left-overs.

When the real APIs are available fine tuning can be done regarding scheduling and timeout.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class QuotesJob {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(QuotesJob.class);

    private String remoteTargets[] = new String[] {
            "https://xyz.free.beeceptor.com",
            "https://xyz.free.beeceptor.com",
            "https://xyz.free.beeceptor.com",
            "https://xyz.free.beeceptor.com"
    };

    private static Map<String, QuotesListener> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static Random random;
    private HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    private AtomicInteger maxSize = new AtomicInteger(remoteTargets.length); 
    private static final long TIMEOUT = 3000;
    
    
    private Map<String, Float> quote = new HashMap<>();
    {
        quote.put("EURUSD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("USDCAD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("NZDUSD", 0.00000f);
        quote.put("AUDUSD", 0.00000f);
        random = new Random();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/6", persistent = false)
    public void perform() {
        logger.info("running quotes update...");
        worker();
        quote.forEach((k, v) -> {
            quote.put(k, random.nextFloat());
        });
        notifyListeners();
    }

    private void worker() {
        counter.lazySet(0);;
        while (counter.intValue() < maxSize.intValue()) {
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(remoteTargets[counter.intValue()]))
                    .header("Accept", "application/json").GET().build();
            CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> responseCompletableFuture = 
                    client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            responseCompletableFuture
            .orTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .whenComplete((resp, t) -> {
                counter.incrementAndGet();
                if (t != null) {
                    logger.error(resp.statusCode() + " Exception: " + t.getMessage());
                    return;
                } 
                if (resp.statusCode()!=200) {
                    logger.info(resp.statusCode() + " Error: " + resp.body());
                    return;
                }
                logger.info(resp.statusCode() + " Result: " + resp.body());
                // -> update quotes with real response
            }).join();
        }
    }

    private void notifyListeners() {
        logger.info("notify listeners: " + quote);
        listeners.forEach((k, v) -> {
            v.consume(quote);
        });
    }

    public void addQuotesListener(String clazz, QuotesListener listener) {
        listeners.put(clazz, listener);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void endJob() {
        counter.lazySet(maxSize.intValue());
        listeners.clear();
    }

}
```